# Weblogic database connectionpool

Tags: connection-pooling, weblogic12c

How to close all the active connections between web logic (12c) and the database without restart the server. 
 I tried to reset using the reset option under the servers - > Monitoring - > JDBC - > Control - > reset . 
 But the connections are still active , Please advise.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you also try `Shutdown` and then `Start`? This is what I normally use.

Comment: Hi Viccari ,thanks for you advise, yes I use that to reset the connection. But would like to know why this  servers - > Monitoring - > JDBC - > Control - > reset  is not working.

Comment: I really don't know. This is what WebLogic help says: `Resets the connection pool in the data source by shutting down and recreating all available database connections in the pool.` Do your connections still count as `Active` when you do so?

Comment: @Vinoth as per definition provided by viccari reset recreates those connections. that's why reset does not reduce active connections.